# How to reset unread sms counter variable?

Tags: java, android, sms, contentobserver

I have content observer which "observes" table changes in "content://sms". My app i'm working on, checks for unread SMS messages and it's working fine. The value of unread messages i'm storing in static variable ( need reference from another class ).

But the thing is that i need to reset this variable to zero, when user navigates to messaging application (SMS Inbox).

Can someone points me to right direction how to do that?

Thanks in advance..=)

Comment: which variable you need to reset ?

Comment: Static variable in my program which counts unread messages. For example, static int counter = 0;

Then i have content observer which gets unread messages, so "counter" variable is the number of unread messages.

I need reset this variable to "0", when user navigates to messaging application (he wants to read , unread messages ).

Hope i was clear enough.

Comment: is my answer solved you design problem

Comment: you want... if you read all messange then set counter=0 right???